# gwt geolocation - PositionError on Safari

Tags: gwt, safari, geolocation

I use the gwt Geolocation-Package (`com.google.gwt.geolocation.client.Geolocation`) to read the current Location on a gwt client.

All woks fine on iPhone, iPad, Android and the Chrome-Browser on desktop.
But when I use it on Safari (5.1.2) on desktop, the Safari asks if he can use the position. When I click "Allow" I get a `PositionError` with errorCode 2 (`POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`).

Has anyone else this problem/solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a wired connection, that's why. Safari 5 apparently returns an error when `navigator.geolocation` is used on a wired connection. To test it out, open the console in Safari 5 and try this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(){console.log("Success!")}, function(){console.log("error")}
);
```

Basically, the Geolocation package is just a wrapper for HTML5's geolocation functionality. In this case, the functionality fails and you get a `PositionError`.